# How to set FPS to 30 with opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

so how? my app is running at 60FPS, but i want 30.

Comment: Draw half as often (seriously). For a more detailed answer, you might consider providing more information, such as what framework you're using if any (such as glut).

Comment: 60fps is most likely synced to the monitor refresh rate.  Why *don't* you want that?

Comment: I'd agree with Seth. interaction with the environment is not part of GL's remit, but part of the platform binding (wgl/glx/egl/...). Which one are you looking at ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a target frame rate, you could measure how long its been since the last time you finished rendering.  From there, you could sleep for targetMsPerFrame - timeElapsed.

Comment: +1 agreed. If your target framerate is 30fps, your targetMsPerFrame is (1000 / 30) milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

one word: `sleep`

Comment: What library or OS's sleep() are you talking about? Many don't have the resolution necessary to achieve smooth framerates.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [WGL_EXT_swap_control](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/wgl_swap_control.txt) or [GLX_EXT_swap_control](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/swap_control.txt) extensions, regarding to your operating system. This is used to control the VSync, but should be usefull to render at half your monitor refresh rate.

Answer (score 0):

@itzWarty has a correct answer on how to set your framerate. It's called "clamping" or "locking" the framerate.

But why do you want to do that? If you're trying to avoid hogging resources, clamping the framerate is good.

Otherwise you might want to let framerate go as fast as possible, in order to make people with great honking graphics cards feel like they didn't waste their money. In that case you need to make your animation time-based rather than frame-based. I.e. scale your animation steps according to how much time has passed since the previous step. E.g.

```
x += dx * (timeNow - timePrev) / typicalDuration; // pseudoCode
```